# Can I use poetry to publish a package that requires higher python version?

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I use CICD tools based on `poetry` to publish python packages to an internal PyPI. I have no control of the CICD tools, which is based on docker with python 3.6. However, due to the language features used in the package to be published, it is compatible only with python 3.8 or higher.

In the `pyproject.toml`, if I specify

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
```

I would get a `NoCompatiblePythonVersionFound` error from `poetry`, which I understand, as the docker has only python 3.6. However, I do not need the package/any codes to run in this docker -- I just need to upload it. The environment which I use this package is on python 3.8.

If I release the python version restriction in `pyproject.toml`, the `poetry` publish works, but I cannot *mark* the package as *requires python 3.8 or above*. The package would be able to be installed but does not work with a lower version.

The question is, is it possible to use `poetry` running with python 3.6 to publish a package which is specified to be compatible with python 3.8 or higher?